Cannot initialize CAN protocol sing HAL functions on STM32F446RE
I am working on a project that involves a STM32 F446RE nucleo board. I am sending CAN frames on the CAN bus of the car.
I am facing a problem that has not always been:
When i am calling the function "MX_CAN1_Init();" itself calling "HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan1)", the value of "hcan1->State" should move from RESET to READY. Indeed it works, until i add the function "HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan1)". In that case, the function "HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan1)" makes the variable moving to LISTENING, instead of READY, leading the function "HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan1)" returning HAL_ERROR; since it's role is to move the same variable from READY to LISTENING.
The problem did not exist before i go on vacations, but right now I can see with the debugger that when executing line "hcan->State = HAL_CAN_STATE_READY;" the real value pointed by the debugger is "HAL_CAN_STATE_LISTENING". I have never coped with such a problem and currently running out of idea...
I started to remove all the functions in the main.c file and add them one by one to see where the problem comes from. Then when i add the function "HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan)", the problem pops up.
int main(void)
{

/* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */
//  uint8_t count = 0;
/* USER CODE END 1 */

/* MCU Configuration-------------------------------------------- 
------------*/

/* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and 
the Systick. */
HAL_Init();

/* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

/* USER CODE END Init */

/* Configure the system clock */
SystemClock_Config();

/* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

/* USER CODE END SysInit */

/* Initialize all configured peripherals */
MX_GPIO_Init();
MX_USART2_UART_Init();
**MX_CAN1_Init()**;
MX_ADC1_Init();
MX_TIM6_Init();
/* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
//CAN_Filter_FIFO0(&hcan1); // Filter config for FIFO0

**if(HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan1) != HAL_OK)**
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

Since the project is quite big, i created another one that only handles CAN transmission to see if the problems pops up, and it does.
Thank you in advance guys.

Please [edit] your question and add your code as a [mre]. Format it as a code block, e.g by using the {} tool of the editor field.
